# Are triple brackets XSS safe in Meteor?

Tags: meteor, handlebars.js, meteor-blaze

I wonder if triple curly brackets sanitize user input within templates to be XSS safe. `<script>` tags won't render out, but how about other creepy XSS hacks?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: they are not safe, this is exactly why you should use double curly brackets most of the time

Comment: But double curly brackets will escape all HTML, which is in my usecase unwanted. ;)

Comment: You should sanitize user input if it's gonna be evalued afterwards. Eg, with  https://atmospherejs.com/djedi/sanitize-html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its not safe, because you can still run malicious code, like this:

```
Template.xx.helpers({
    'bad':function() {
        return "<a href="#" onclick="alert('compromised');">CLICK ME PLZ!</a>";
    }
});
```

The template

```
<template name="xx"> {{{bad}}} </template>
```

This means the user needs to click the button, but you could make it more of a sure thing by use other events such as onmouseover:

A floating div can take up all the space & use mouseovers to assure the code is run. This can be used as the return value in this example:

```
<div style="width:100%; height:100%; position: fixed;" onmouseover="console.log('haha');"></div>
```

You can also have other exploits such as changing page content via CSS (using `content:` or higher `z-index` floating divs to change the page's content.